# Python: difficult in converting csv to list of list

Tags: python, list, csv

I want to read a .csv file which has data format like

```
-179.750  71.250   -26.7   -19.5   -22.5   -22.3    -8.0    -0.6     2.5 
-179.750  68.750   -28.5   -21.3   -24.4   -24.4    -8.0     0.0     4.0
.....
```

and I want to convert to list of list as

```
[[-179.750,71.250..2.5],[-179.750,68.750,..4.0]
```

I use csv module to read csv file as:

```
 import csv
 csvfile= open('test.csv','rU')
 reader = csv.reader(csvfile,quotechar=" ")
 allRows = list(reader)
 print allRows
```

The output is

```
[['-179.750  68.750 ... -26.5'],['-179.750  68.250 ... 4.0']]
```

please give me some idea so that i can modify and get my output. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just guessing... Maybe `quotechar` is not what you think it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `quotechar` argument is for the character to be used to enclose a data entry containing delimiters, etc.  You should use `delimiter`.

If you want numbers out, not lists of strings, you'll want to also put the results through `float`.

```
import csv
csvfile= open('test.csv','rU')
reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=" ")
allRows = list(reader)
print allRows

numData=[ [float(i) for i in row]
          for row in allRows]

print numData
```

Comment: Thank you sir but it is saying "could not convert string to float ".

Comment: @Jigs then one of your entries isn't a valid floating point number.  In Python 2.7 the error message should tell you what the problem value is, e.g., "ValueError: could not convert string to float: foo".  You can either fix your data file (should they all be numbers?), or you could write a function, say, `tofloat`, that tries to convert and on failure returns None or some other value signalling an invalid value.  (None can't be used in arithmetic - whether that's good or bad for your case only you can tell.)

Comment: [missed edit window] Also, if you don't need numbers, just use `allRows` and don't create `numData`.

Comment: It was valueError and i will correct it. Thank you sir for your valuable and quick response